# Why has my laptop stopped reading DVD's?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, dvd, dell-inspiron, cd

My dad's Windows 7 Dell Inspiron laptop reads CD's just fine, but not DVD's. He used to watch DVD's on his laptop all the time, but now it won't even recognize the disk. File explorer says to insert a disk when a DVD is in there, even though it recognizes CD's.

Does anyone have any ideas about what the problem might be? Is there anything I can look into to try to fix it?

Comment: try uninstall driver then refresh in device manager

Comment: Best guess would be dirty read heads/optics; especially if you have smokers or pets. Easier to replace than clean.

Comment: Are you saying the read heads/optics can be replaced, or are you saying the whole laptop would have to be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an HP computer. To solve it, I borrowed a external disk reader from a friend and plugged it into the USB port. It ran everything just fine so I decided the problem was most likely my internal disk reader. I purchased the correct one and installed it. That took about a half an hour to complete and everything was up and running.
Good luck!

Comment: Are you saying your solution was to take out the internal disk reader and replace it with a new one? I don't think that's possible with a laptop. But maybe an external disk reader can be a permanent solution.